# Get public facing IP address. Different websites giving different IP's

Tags: azure, powershell, ip, powershell-core

I don't know too much about networking concepts, trying to get my public facing IP address programatically (powershell preferred)

Trying these different websites

- https://www.whatismyip.com/ #  Only this one seems to work when I am trying to RDP into the machine (Azure NSG inbound rules)
- ipinfo.ipidea.io # this gives my modem/ISP address
- https://api.ipify.org/?format=json # this gives my modem/ISP address
- ifconfig.me/ip # this gives my modem/ISP address

Is there an alternative way to get the IP address shown by whatismyip.com website [for free]?

> please don't go into "pay them you cheap pos"; It's a company project, and my boss man doesn't want to spend anything currently

I could use my local computer IP address, but we use a VPN (company wide), and hoping to get the address of this VPN provider

Edit: adding more clarity

I think I need the IP address of the VPN provider I am connected to. The browser/whatismyip is somehow able to get it. I need this address programmatically. Are there any free other APIs that provide this info?

Comment: @mklement0 I am trying to get my VPN IP address from my local laptop. Realizing this might not be the right way to restrict access to my NSG, there has to be a better way other than hardcoding IP addresses. Like some security groups?

Answer (score 3):

Given you want to use Powershell,

you can try to invoke a Web request to the api.ipify.org

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://api.ipify.org/").Content
```

Or

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://api.ipify.org
```

The response will be your IP address.

If you want the VPN IP address, you can use the code below

```
(Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Your VPN Connection Name").IPv4Address
```

To find the VPN connection name, assuming you are using Windows, you can check the VPN connections on the *Network & internet* settings.

More info here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-to-a-vpn-in-windows-3d29aeb1-f497-f6b7-7633-115722c1009c

*Edited to include the option shared by @mklement0*

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it properly. I need the IP address of the VPN provider I am connected to, from my local computer. The one you mentioned gives me my modem IP address, but somehow the browser is able to determine the IP address of the VPN provider?

Comment: @scorpion35 just updated the response, check the latest command I shared and see if you get what you are expecting

Comment: Thank you @HugoBarona, but the we use a 3rd party app (cisco connect) to connect to VPN. It's not identified by `Get-NetAdapter`

Comment: Give it a try with NetIPconfiguration then

Comment: Get-NetIPConfiguration | where {$_.InterfaceDescription -like "Cisco*"} | select IPv4Address

Comment: Still no luck. `Get-NetIPConfiguration` only my wi-fi and ethernet interfaces. Somehow the VPN one is only recognized via a browser